# Removing stitching from jacket

Tags: material-selection, sewing

I have a sports jacket from a team I used to play for. It's a very high quality jacket and I would like to continue wearing it, but the team name is written in large text across the upper-back of the jacket.

I would like to remove this writing but I don't know how. It appears to be some kind of stitching but it's quite heavily coupled with the jacket material.

Is it possible to remove this? See attached photos:

Outside:
[image]

Inside:
[image]

I've tried cutting just a small section of one of the letters but I'm not sure if it's working properly. The stitching is so fine that there's still a thin white outline:
[image]

---

**Edit**: Thanks everyone for the feedback! This strategy is working. It will take a very long time, but I will get there:
[image]

Comment: You have to just keep going, use a magnifying glass to muscle through when necessary. The seam ripper is your best tool for this job. You may want to use a pin occasionally. I've done it on a Champion hoodie. As long as the jacket is not too old, the fabric behind the embroidery stitching should still match. That was my error with my hoodie, since it was old and faded, the word on the dark fabric that was covered by the stitching is still visible.

Comment: Please see the edit. I've starting applying the techniques mentioned here. Thanks!

Comment: You got it! low heat iron when you're finished will help get out the lumps. :)

Answer (score 3):

I’d be using tweezers to remove the final remaining thread with a magnifying glass if needed. If the jacket's fabric is synthetic do this more carefully than if it is cotton.

You might need to as a last step, go over it with a green kitchen scourer. This will help remove fibres caught in the actual jacket fabric. Again if synthetic, go gently.

Comment: Please see the edit. I've starting applying the techniques mentioned here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This article lists several methods: https://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Embroidery

Based on your pictures alone, I can’t tell quite what you mean about the outline. The first step I would try is to use clear packing tape or masking tape to try to lift the bits of thread out.

Comment: A proper answer is usually 'isolated' from external sources, so that it remains useful even when the linked page has been (re)moved, but I can imagine you skipped getting into it more extensively for lack of detail in the question.

Comment: Yes, I posted because I couldn’t tell what was actually wrong with the pictured method from the picture. Even after zooming, it looked like the removal process is going as normal so I was hoping the steps could give OP some ideas of verbiage to describe what exactly they’re stuck on.

Comment: Please see the edit. I've starting applying the techniques mentioned here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A great technique for removing embroidery stitches popped up in a post on steemit 
https://steemit.com/needleworkmonday/@sheilamenher/fabrics-embroidery-and-designs-how-to-undo-embroidered-cap-without-detail

[Fabrics, Embroidery and Designs - how to undo embroidered cap without detail](https://steemit.com/needleworkmonday/@sheilamenher/fabrics-embroidery-and-designs-how-to-undo-embroidered-cap-without-detail)

@sheilamenher suggests using a shaver, brush and snippers. Check it out, she provides instructions. 
If you’ve already finished, please let us see the results. Thanks!
I also resteemed it on my blog @oceanmoon